# Facebook Invite to URL of application not application home page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi I am creating a Facebook Picture Design application

When a user A will go to application, then he can take part in group competition and can invite other friends to join his team to improve his drawing. User A will create a drawing and his invited friends can join and improve his drawing.

Now the question is if user will send normal invitation (method: apprequest) to his friends. How his friends will redirected to his drawing page after facebook auth.

Ex: user's A drawing URL:
  app.facebook.com/art/drawing/1

and respectivily for other users
  app.facebook.com/art/drawing/2
  app.facebook.com/art/drawing/3 ..... and so on..

Users a drawing page is at controller drawing/1 for invited user after auth can be redirected to app.facebook.com/art/drawing/1

Answer (score 1):

When you send a request you can also send some data along with the request. After your request is sent, Facebook will return the new request's **id** to your app, which your app may store in a local database. Later, the user clicks on the request notification and is redirected to your app's *canvas* page. When the user lands on your *canvas* page, your app can can either..

- use the **data** parameter
- use the request id

...to determine what is shown to the user.

For example, if you decide to use the **data** parameter, simply pass the *drawing id* as the data parameter whilst creating the request so that when your user lands on the canvas page your app will display the proper drawing.